# MVVM c# how to load async data into a property?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I wonder if there's a better approach to load async data into a property. now I create an async function and raise a Task in the Get part of the property like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<CProyecto> prope;

public ObservableCollection<CProyecto> Prope
{
    get 
    {
        if (prope == null)
        {
            Task.Run(()=> LoadData()).Wait();
        }

        return proyectos;
    }
    set 
    { 
        prope = value; 
        RaisePropertyChanged(); 
    }
}

async private Task LoadData() 
{
    Prope = await clsStaticClassDataLoader.GetDataFromWebService();
}
```

This approach works, but I don't like the use of .Wait, because that can freeze the screen if the service doesn´t respond fast.

Can you please guide me on this matter?

thanks in advance

Comment: What's the point of starting a new task if you call the Wait() method to block the calling thread anyway....?

Comment: Regarding async properties you should read this: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html

Comment: Use a `loaded event` to fetch data from external source.  Make the event async and bind to your collection.

Comment: Worst. Property. Ever.

Comment: Eldho, loaded_event? from the xaml page ? .
 thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The way I handled this was to start the process of loading the property when the object was constructed, but I did not await the result.  Since the property notifies when it is populated, the bindings worked just fine.  Essentially it works like this:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<CProyecto> prope;

    public ObservableCollection<CProyecto> Prope
    {
        get { return prope; }
        set { prope = value; RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Prope)); }
    }

    public MyClass()
    {
        // Don't wait or await.  When it's ready
        // the UI will get notified.
        LoadData();
    }

    async private Task LoadData() 
    {
        Prope = await clsStaticClassDataLoader.GetDataFromWebService();
    }
}
```

This works very well, and does not cause any delays or stuttering in the UI.  If you want the collection to never be `null` (a good practice IMO), you can pre-initialize the `prope` field with an empty collection.

Comment: This is a good first step, but will silently swallow errors thrown by `LoadData`. A more comprehensive approach would have a top-level `try`/`catch` in `LoadData` and update your UI with an error notification.

Comment: Agreed.  I am describing the _approach_ I took.  However, you have the correct location to do the error handling.

Comment: but you can not call async methods from a constructor, is the same problem with the property. You got this warning https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873131.aspx

Comment: @KillemAll, you get the warning because you can't `await` the response.  The goal here is not to await, but to start the process of loading the data.  We get notified in another way that the work is done.

Comment: I did just like you said and the only way I got not warning is doing `LoadData().wait();` or what I am missing?

Comment: Just ignore the warning.  It's not a compile failure.  You can suppress the warning with the `[SuppressMessage]` attribute since it's _intentional_.

Comment: I really don´t like avoid warnings, so I did something else,.. this: `Task.Run(() => LoadData());`  Doing in another task the warning is gone and works perfectly, thanks!!!

Comment: or just declare the LoadData as a void: "async private void LoadData()". An 'async void' is just as async, but cann't be awaited, hence no warning

Answer (score 12):

I suggest you read my MSDN article on [async MVVM data-binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx). I have [a library](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.Mvvm.Async) ([github link](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm)) that provides a [`NotifyTask<T>` type](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.Mvvm.Async/1.0.0-eta-05/netstandard1.0/doc/Nito.Mvvm.NotifyTask%271), which can be used as such:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public NotifyTask<ObservableCollection<CProyecto>> Prope { get; private set; }

  public MyClass()
  {
    // Synchronously *start* the operation.
    Prope = NotifyTask.Create(LoadDataAsync());
  }

  async private Task<ObservableCollection<CProyecto>> LoadDataAsync()
  {
    return await clsStaticClassDataLoader.GetDataFromWebService();
  }
}
```

Then your databinding would operate on `Prope.Result`.

The advantage of this approach is that you can also use databinding to hide/show busy indicators (`Prope.IsNotCompleted`), show controls when the data is available (`Prope.IsSuccessfullyCompleted`), and error notifications (`Prope.IsFaulted` / `Prope.ErrorMessage`).

Also, you can specify a non-`null` default value, if you wish:

```
Prope = NotifyTask.Create(LoadDataAsync(), new ObservableCollection<CProyecto>());
```

Comment: library is found on github now:
https://github.com/StephenCleary/Mvvm.Async

Comment: Ok, dumb question, how do I load this library into my project?  I'm using the old version of INotifyTaskCompletion and NotifyTaskCompletion.Create().  I found it on an old post of Stephen Cleary's and it was in a Nuget package of Nito.AsyncEx.Strong.

Comment: @FLAdmin: Sorry for the confusion; the asynchronous MVVM types I think have gone through more package renames than any other code I've written. They're currently at: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.Mvvm.Async

Comment: Thanks so much Stephen.  I'll import that package.  I actually copied your NotifyTaskCompletion class from your article and it worked great. to keep me going. 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2014/march/async-programming-patterns-for-asynchronous-mvvm-applications-data-binding

Answer (score 0):

Your current implementation of the `Prope` property doesn't make much sense. It is pointless to execute the `LoadData` method on a background thread since you block the main thread anyway when you call `Wait()`. You might as well call `Wait()` directly on the task returned by the `LoadData()` method:

```
//BAD IMPLEMENTATION!
private ObservableCollection<CProyecto> prope;
public ObservableCollection<CProyecto> Prope
{
    get
    {
        if (prope == null)
            LoadData().Wait();
        return proyectos;
    }
    set { prope = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
}
```

The above implementation is still a bad one. The getter of a property is not supposed to perform an asynchronous operation. You should read @Stephen Cleary's blog post on the subject: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html

...and look into his `NotifyTaskCompletion` type in his `AsyncEx` library: https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx

Comment: Well It looks like don´t have sense but actually it have sense, if I don't do that the system hangs when I call my webservice,. I guess that is because the way I call the  service  var Response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;