# How to execute operations after a UserControl is fully displayed?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a main window that I use to display one of two possible views (ConfigView & AnalyzeView):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ConfigViewModel}">
        <v:ConfigView/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AnalyzeViewModel}">
        <v:AnalyzeView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentViewModel}" />
</Grid>
```

When transitioning from the ConfigView to the AnalyzeView, I want to first wait for the AnalyzeView to be fully displayed in the main window before performing the analysis operations. I initially added an EventTrigger for the Loaded event in the AnalyzeView as a way of starting the analysis operations:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadedCmd}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

However, I found that this event would be triggered before the AnalyzeView was displayed in the main window. In fact, it seems that the AnalyzeView is not displayed in the main window until sometime after the Loaded event.

Is there any event that I can trigger on so that I can start the analysis operations only after the AnalyzeView is fully displayed in the main window?

EDIT:
Ultimately, may main goal is to display a progress bar on the AnalyzeView that shows the progress of the analysis operations. Essentially, the user presses a "Start Analysis" button which transitions to the AnalyzeView and begins the analysis process, updating a progress bar as it goes.

Comment: Expose an ICommand on the surface of the view model and in a DependencyProperty on the window.  Bind them together.  Add an event listener to that control, and on its Loaded event fire the ICommand.  Remember--MVVM != no codebehind.

Comment: @mm8 Hey, so were you, so everything's cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're seeing is that the Loaded event fires after the UI thread has finished loading the control but if you have a breakpoint set in LoadedCmd, you'll notice AnalyzeView isn't rendered yet.

This is because WPF has a background rendering thread which hasn't yet had a chance to render the control, even though the UI thread is finished with it's loading. When your program hits the breakpoint, all threads are broken into and so it appears as though AnalyzeView never finished loading.

I'd suggest trying to allow the command to perform whatever operations are necessary to populate the AnalyzeView just as you've laid out here- if they're long running, and do not have to be loaded into DependencyProperties, you should run them asynchronously so that the UI thread can respond to input.

Edit 1: Following up on your comment's on @wimpSquad's answer - to keep this MVVM and show progress while keeping the UI responsive, you definitely will want to look into Tasks and reporting progress. Stephen Cleary has a good article  [here](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html).

Further Reading: 
 [WPF Threading Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/threading-model) 
[Async Loading Of Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368904/mvvm-c-sharp-how-to-load-async-data-into-a-property)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I thought I was using Tasks correctly, but did not realize that using Task.Wait() on the UI thread would block it. I ended up using a different method and am looking into adapting it to async/await.

Answer (score 0):

So, looks like you can - [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708039/what-event-is-fired-when-a-usercontrol-is-displayed) - but I'm curious as to why you would want to.  The View should only be a rendering of exposed properties in the ViewModel.  What is your use case for this (morbid curiosity)?

Edit: based on your updated question, I'd recommend the following:

Load the AnalyzeView as normal, with a `<ProgressBar/>` bound to an exposed property that is incremented by the ViewModel (during your analysis process).  This synchronicity can be achieved through event binding, and made even easier with `PropertyChanged.Fody` NuGet package, with the `[ImplementPropertyChanged]` attribute. This attribute was renamed in a more recent version of the package than what I am using, but with a quick search you should find what you are looking for there.  In any case, the attribute handles triggering automatically, so as properties are updated in your ViewModel, the bound properties on your View update as well.

If you'd like to see an example of a `<ProgressBar/>` being used, just let me know.  I've got one around here somewhere.

Comment: Ultimately, I want to display on progress bar on the AnalyzeView that shows the progress of the analysis operations. Essentially, the user presses a "Start Analysis" button which transitions to the AnalyzeView and begins the analysis process, updating a progress bar as it goes.

Comment: Also, I'm looking for a way to do this with MVVM.

Comment: I implemented a basic progress bar that is updated by the analysis process which is kicked off by the AnalysisViewModel. However, I'm still not seeing the progress bar update because the AnalysisView isn't loaded until after all of the analysis process has completed. Right now, I'm using the "Loaded" event for the AnalysisView to start the analysis process. Is there a better event/method to use instead of the "Loaded" event? How can I start the analysis process (including updating the progress bar) after the AnalysisView is visible in the main window?