# Retrieving data from a database in the background while a dialog is loading

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, task, dapper

I'm using Dapper in a WPF application to retrieve data from a database for a couple of combobox lists.  I'd like that retrieval to occur in the background; it will prevent a small delay when the user opens the first combo box.

So I've done this:

```
private Task<IEnumerable<T_Program>> _allTapes;

// Binds to combobox ItemsSource
public IEnumerable<T_Program> Tapes => 
   _allTapes.Result.Where(x => x.Program.Equals(Program));
```

And in the constructor of my View Model:

```
_allTapes = _conn.GetAllAsync<T_Program>();
```

But I didn't get the "performance improvement" that I wanted.

Hovering the cursor over `_allTapes` during debugging yields the following description:

```
Id = 6722, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"
```

So it would appear that Dapper's `GetAllAsync` method doesn't actually execute the query until it is compelled by retrieving `Result` from the Task.

How do I get the background execution that I want?

Comment: You shouldn't use `.Result`, instead `await` the method.

Comment: @DavidG: Where?

Comment: `_allTapes.Result` *blocks*. Apart from that, `Tapes` should be a proper property whose setter raises the `PropertyChanged` event. No matter how the data is loaded, the final step should be to set that propert. This will result in the UI refreshing itself

Comment: Been a long time since I did any WPF so I'm not completely sure off the top of my head. Perhaps something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43371368/1663001) if you're doing MVVM.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: PropertyChanged is already handled.  See [Fody.PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged).

Comment: @RobertHarvey for *Tapes*?

Comment: Yes, for all of the public properties.

Comment: No it's not. That's because Tapes only has a getter, it's never set

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Yes, you're right.  Let's shelve the PropertyChanged discussion for now; I don't need notification on this particular property.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you do, otherwise the UI will never know that it has to update itself. Bidning won't work otherwise. Again, this is overcomplicating things

Comment: The binding is already working; it's just not executing the query until the dropdown list is compelled.

Comment: First of all, the property should be `public T_Program[] Tapes {get;private set;}` at least. As long as `PropertyChanged(Tapes)` is raised, it doesn't matter how it's implemented. Second, the data loader method (not the constructor) should set the propert in its last step, eg `Tapes = await __conn.GetAllAsync<T_Program>();`. That means the loader itself has to be `async Task` at least

Comment: @RobertHarvey if the binding worked you'd get the data. That's because the data is *not* available when the *first* binding is made. It will be loaded *asynchronously later*. When that happens the event should be raised again. The simplest way to do that is by just setting the property again

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: "loaded asynchronously later" is exactly the behavior I don't want.  I don't need lazy loading; I need eager, one-time loading.

Comment: @RobertHarvey anyway, there's no support for async constructors which means you can't execute `_conn.GetAllAsync<T_Program>()` asynchronously in the constructor and get the results. Most MVVM frameworks call a separate `Initialize()` method after construction to perform work that can't be done in the constructor. *You could try* calling the loader method as a fire and forget method, but the View may be displayed empty until the data is loaded

Comment: @RobertHarvey then you are asking for the opposite of your question. You are asking how to load in the *foreground*. *Background* loading means *asynchronous* loading

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: The second sentence of my post is "I'd like that retrieval to occur in the background."  I don't mean "stand up an asynchronous Task and return, but don't execute the operation until the result is compelled."

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, and that's what asynchronous loading means, what `GetAllAsync()` does. If you want the data to be loaded before the constructor completes, use `GetAll()` instead of `GetAllAsync()`. Otherwise you'd have to use `GetAllAsync().Result` in the constructor which is pointless

Comment: `GetAll()` will block, which is not what I want.

Comment: @RobertHarvey asynchronous doesn't mean Lazy<T>. If you don't want the UI to freeze while loading data, you need to set the property once the data is loaded. That means you need `async/await`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Ergo the question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I already answered how it should be done. In the background means async/await. That's what you are already doing. `_allTapes.Result` on the other hand is *equivalent* to `GetAll()` - actually identical to `GetAllAsynct().Result`. After all, `_allTapes` *contains* the task returned by `GetAllAsync()`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey if you don't want to display an empty combo, you have two options. One option is to load the data in the background *before* you construct the UI. The app won't freeze and you still get a full combo. The other option is to use whatever initialization support is provided by your MVVM framework.

Comment: You keep telling me what I'm doing wrong, but not how to fix it.  The constructor cannot be made async.

Comment: @RobertHarvey are you using an MVVM framework or writing everything from scratch? Caliburn.Micro for example provides conventions that allow binding directly to properties and async methods

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've already explained how to fix it. Either *don't* do it in the constructor, or create an `async Task`  loader method that sets the property in the end eg `private async Task LoadCombo(){ Tapes = await _conn.GetAllAsync<T_Program>();}`. In the constructor call it and store the task in a field eg `_justaField=LoadCombo();` That field isn't needed, it's there to prevent the GC from collecting the task. I'd prefer to use the MVVM framework's navigation/initialization support though

Comment: @DavidG: That's a very useful link, thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify why you wouldn't simply mark the `Binding` to `IsAsync= true` then do all the queries synchronized but instead do this custom approach?

Comment: @tweray: Will that give me the background loading behavior that I want?

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, all Binding marked `IsAsync= true` will do most binding operations (in your case, the db query) out of the UI thread, thus not freezing the UI.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently just assigning the Task object to _allTapes.

Try

```
_allTapes = await _conn.GetAllAsync<T_Program>().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: The View Model's constructor cannot be made `async`.  See https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html

Comment: In which case, rather that doing this in the constructor, use a AsyncLazy property http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.  According to Stephen, this won't retrieve the property (compel the query) until it's asked for the first time, which probably leaves me back where I started.

Comment: If you want the loading done at the earliest opportunity, then either do a "fire and forget" task in the constructor - this is not recommended though as any exceptions will be lost, or use an async method that is triggered from OnLoaded of the view (eg via event to command). I normally use the latter, and populate an ObservableCollection as my combo source - you have to be mindful of threading issues though.

Comment: This won't update the U.I. any faster than using an AsyncLazy property though - assuminng the ComboBox's ItemSource is bound to LazyProperty.Result. The delay is always the time taken to process the database query.

Comment: Yes, but if I can get that query to run in the background when the dialog loads...  It takes users a couple of seconds to visually process the dialog I show them anyway.  So they're not going to open that combo immediately anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So this is the solution that I've settled on... In the View Model constructor:

```
_allTapes = Task.Run(() => _conn.GetAll<T_Program>());
```

**IsAsync=True** must be added to the combo box `ItemsSource` binding to prevent the form load from blocking.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Tapes, IsAsync=True}"
```

It turns out that this was only part of the problem.  To get good performance from the combo box, I had to add a virtualizing stack panel to it:

```xml
<ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemsPanel>
```

And there aren't even that many items in the combo (perhaps a hundred).

Comment: The number of items usually doesn't have that much impact in the rendering. It is usually down to the complex `DataTemplate` for the items. Is it more complex than just a `TextBlock`? FYI `Label` is an overkill for just a text display.

Comment: @XAMlMAX The data template is the stock standard one that comes with the WPF combo box.